Eslint пропускает вопрос 'В каком формате хронить config файл?', подсветка ошибок не работает
У меня и моих коллеги возникли проблемы с eslint. Во время инициализации программа установки пропускает вопрос "В каком формате должен храниться файл конфигурации?".  Файл .js создается автоматически. В этом случае возникает ошибка.
[{
    "resource": "/Users/idris/development/newFolder2/eslint.config.mjs",
    "owner": "eslint",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Parsing error: Unexpected token import",
    "source": "eslint",
    "startLineNumber": 9,
    "startColumn": 34,
    "endLineNumber": 9,
    "endColumn": 34
}]

введите сюда описание изображения Подсветка не работает. Но если запустить npx eslint script.js, то на терминал выводятся ошибки, и все, кажется, работает. Решение проблемы заключается в удалении файла .js и создании .json вручную. Но поскольку мы только учимся и создаем по нескольку проектов каждый день, это неудобно. В чем может быть проблема? Почему пропущен вопрос о формате файла конфигурации? P.S. Macbook m1 2020, sonoma 14.4, последняя версия клиента, установлено расширение eslint, последняя версия node js, последняя версия npm.
